# National Public Transportation APIs

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3

I've recently found myself in need of a national level public transportation API that provides public transportation routing data in a way similar to Google's transit routing service. Unfortunately, google has locked down all of their public transportation information and refuses to make it available through any of their APIs. Is there some other service that provides this kind of information or am I just a madman in pursuit of some crazy pipe dream?

(I've looked into OpenTripPlanner, but it looks like it would require enterprise level resources to deploy that with every publicly available GTFS (google transit feed specification) in the United States.)

Comment: Just a comment, Google licenses the data from transit providers, and those providers do not give Google the right to transmit the data through the API. It's not Google that is trying to hold that information, but the transit agencies.

Comment: That's really interesting. Most (if not all) of the providers that are on Google transit also offer the relevant datasets to the public free of charge (just not in a form that's usable to people without a significant amount of resources), so I'm not entirely sure why they would insist that Google not share the information over its API.

Answer (score 0):

It's surely not free, but you can try Jeppeson's service:
http://ww1.jeppesen.com/main/corporate/land/journey-planning/